# Как правильно реализовать управление фрагментами в Moxy?

Tags: android, android-fragment, mvp, moxy

Решила сделать всё "как надо", поэтому начала переводить старый проект с лапшекодом на Moxy.

У меня есть одна активити, которая показывает несколько фрагментов. Вопрос: как (где?) правильно реализовать смену фрагментов?
Как мне кажется, варианта три:

1. Имплиментировать во все фрагменты `MainView extends MvpView`, в которой будет метод `showFragment()`, и переопределить его в каждом фрагменте отдельно. То есть фрагмент сам будет вызывать другой фрагмент. Но это, кмк, не совсем верно - насколько помню, фрагментами всё же должна управлять Activity.
2. Сделать `MainView extends MvpView`, сделать в нем метод `showFragment(String tag)`, Переопределить в Activity этот метод так, чтобы в зависимости от тега показывались разные фрагменты. Сделать в этой же Activity метод `public MainPresenter getPresenter()`. Тогда фрагменты будут сменять друг друга через Activity: `getActivity().getPresenter().showFragment("Tag")`. Не уверена, что это грамотно с точки зрения MVP, к тому же немного запутанно.
3. Изменить тип presenter'а Activity на `PresenterType.GLOBAL`. С этим я пока не разобралась до конца.

Ни один из этих вариантов мне не кажется правильным. Поэтому очень нужна подсказка.

Пока я делаю во фрагменте `@InjectPresenter` презентера из Activity (а соответственно, приходится делать и `implements MainView`), и вызываю у этого презентера метод смены фрагментов. Но это, ожидаемо, не работает, так как переопределенный во фрагменте метод из `MainView` пуст.

```
 public class FragmentA extends MvpAppCompatFragment implements AView, MainView {

   private static final String ARGS = "args";
   public static final String MAIN_FRAGMENT = "main";

    @InjectPresenter
    APresenter aPresenter;
    @InjectPresenter
    MainPresenter mainPresenter;

    @ProvidePresenter
    ExploitTypePresenter provideTitlePresenter() {
        int type = getArguments().getInt(ARGS_TYPE);
        return new ExploitTypePresenter(type);
    }

    public static FragmentA getInstance(int intArgs) {
        FragmentA fragment = new FragmentA();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARGS, intArgs);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public FragmentA() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
        Butterknife.bind(this, view);
        return view;
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.save_button) void onSave() {
        aPresenter.onSaved();
        mainPresenter.showFragment(MAIN_FRAGMENT);
    }

    @Override
    public void showFragment(String tag) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте либу https://github.com/terrakok/Cicerone - она как раз создана для решения задачи навигации.

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько вариантов как реализовать переключение фрагментов или другими словами "навигацию" в конкретно вашем случае (одна сингл-активити со своими собсвтенным презентером для отображения фрагментов) или похожем.

Вообще, задача на самом деле звучит так - как наладить "общение" между разными презентерами:

1. Добавить новый слой "интеракторов", через который презентеры будут друг с другом общаться. Презентеры у хост активити и у фрагментов будут иметь экземпляр "интерактора", через который будут обмениваться событиями/сообщениями - это можно сделать на листенерах или, лучше, на Rx подходе - в интеракторе сидит обзёрвабл и презентеры кому он интересен следят за его изменениями.
2. Коммуницировать через активити. Завести интерфейс для активити и держать сылку на него в ваших фрагментах, презентеры фрагментов будут вызывать методы фрагментов а те будут дёргать интерфейс активити, и она будет что-то там делать/переключать. По сути можно сказать что это общение "через вью" и может показаться что это "неправильно", но этот способ допустим и место быть - фрагменты живут не сами по себе в любом случае, так или иначе им нужна активити и нам в итоге нужен фрагмент менеджер.
3. Затянуть библиотеку Cicerone, экземпляр роутера чичероневского хранить в презентерах и дергать этот роутер для переключения фрагментов. Этот вариант при использовании MVP и Moxy в частности - наиболее подходящий, поэтому очень мало в интернете примеров Moxy без Cicerone

Так же на ютубе есть отличный доклад от авторов "Moxy. Как правильно пользоваться? / Юрий Шмаков (Arello Mobile)" - советую к просмотру